# Repeat MySql query until result is found (with delay)

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am building a PHP webshop, where on the thank-you-page of the shopping process the results of the payment status/cancellation might not yet be sent from the payment service provider.

So, when retrieving that status from SHOP_PAYMENTS, the updated record might not be there yet.

The query is simple:

```
$check_status = "SELECT * FROM SHOP_PAYMENTS WHERE order_id = '$orderID' AND status <> ''";
```

When no result on **status** (we have the order_id), I'd like to repeat it with a delay: say every 2 seconds with a max of 3 times repeat.

And, of course, when **any status** is found, break and give the results.

I know `SELECT REPEAT()` exists (and tried it), but it just fires it 3 times in a row.

Is there any other way to accomplish this?

Comment: You are likely open to a critical SQL injection vulnerability as you've concatenated PHP variables directly into your query string - you really should be using prepared statements and parameterized queries to correctly and safely interpolate PHP variable values into your queries.

Comment: In any event, can you share the code of your attempts you describe as a [mre]? It would help greatly in getting you to some concrete, actionable advice/a solution if we know what you've tried so far and what doesn't meet your requirements. [ask]

Comment: Sorry there, just wrote it down like this to make it look as simple as possible.

Comment: Sorry, typo. Will correct it.

Comment: @KJS it looks like esqew provided an explanation of the downvote. The premise is that you researched and attempted to solve the problem prior to asking. See [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/1144627)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to use a `do ... while()` statement to iterate over and execute the query, delaying the next iteration by using `sleep()` or for greater accuracy `usleep()`.

However, it would be more advantageous to have a message queue send and determine the status from the payment gateway, prior to moving forward with a response to the client.

The below example assumes that mysqli is configured with `MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT`, instead of checking for true/false

Additionally, `status` must not be nullable, otherwise a condition of `status IS NOT NULL AND status != ""` is needed to check for null or an empty string.

```php
$i = 0;
do {
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT `status` FROM `SHOP_PAYMENTS` WHERE `order_id` = ? AND `status` != ''");
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $id);
    $id = $orderID; //bind the order_id param to the value of $orderID 
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($status);
    $stmt->fetch();
    $stmt->close(); //important - mysqli may not unlock the results unless the prepared statement is closed and recreated
    if (!$status) {
        //delay next iteration by two seconds if a status is not found
        sleep(2);
    }
//stop checking if there is a status or iterations exceeds 2
} while (!$status && $i++ < 2);
if ($status) {
   //... do something
}
```

---

PDO + Sqlite Example demonstrating the repeated query with delay
https://3v4l.org/IFc2i